# Linking Error using Cmake file to build Qt project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, cmake, qt5

I am trying to build a qt project using cmake. As a startinng point, I started off by just writing a simple code in qt creator, which contains main.cpp, mainwindow.cpp & mainwindow.h. Below are my CMakeLists.txt configuration.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(testproject)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Core)

get_target_property(QtCore_location Qt5::Core LOCATION)

# Tell CMake to create the executable
add_executable(testproject WIN32 main.cpp mainwindow.cpp)

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(testproject Qt5::Widgets)
```

Cmake did successfully generate the VS Project files. However, when I try to build them in visual studio, it gives me linking errors. Some of the errors are listed below. I could not post the whole error list as it is too long.

```
>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QWidget::show(void)" (__imp_?show@QWidget@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QApplication::QApplication(int &,char * *,int)" (__imp_??0QApplication@@QEAA@AEAHPEAPEADH@Z) referenced in function main
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QApplication::~QApplication(void)" (__imp_??1QApplication@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static int __cdecl QApplication::exec(void)" (__imp_?exec@QApplication@@SAHXZ) referenced in function main
2>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QMetaObject::Connection::~Connection(void)" (__imp_??1Connection@QMetaObject@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
2>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QString::~QString(void)" (__imp_??1QString@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
2>testproject_automoc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual int __cdecl QMainWindow::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (__imp_?qt_metacall@QMainWindow@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MainWindow@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
2>testproject_automoc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static struct QMetaObject const QMainWindow::staticMetaObject" (__imp_?staticMetaObject@QMainWindow@@2UQMetaObject@@B) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'public: static struct QMetaObject const MainWindow::staticMetaObject''(void)" (??__E?staticMetaObject@MainWindow@@2UQMetaObject@@B@@YAXXZ)
2>MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup
```

I am using Qt5.3.1, cmake 3.0.2 and visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this issue you have to remove the WIN32 statement from
`add_executable(testproject WIN32 main.cpp mainwindow.cpp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

- Check the source file names in the `add_executable` command inside your `CMakeLists.txt` for spelling errors. File names in the source list that do not exist will produce the linker error `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced`.
- What does your entry point function look like?

  - `WinMain` requires `add_executable(testproject WIN32 main.cpp mainwindow.cpp)`
  - `main` requires `add_executable(testproject main.cpp mainwindow.cpp)`
  - **Note**: I suggest using `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, as it will be portable to linux, while using `WinMain` won't.

Comment: Please read [CMake official documentation entry][https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html]. You can still have `int main(...)` in your code and have the `WIN32` property.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error, I was using the `x64-Debug` configuration in *Visual Studio*, but the variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in *CMake* was the path of *x86 Qt*, so the linker tried to link the *x86 Qt* libraries to the *x64* program and the error occurred.

The solution is correcting the *Visual Studio* configuration and the *Qt* path to the same architecture.

Comment: Unless can be done in CMake itself I find this solution not a good option (even if it actually works, which I cannot confirm). Whenever CMake is ran and the projects are regenerated, all these changes will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

You have to link against `QtCore`, you only link against `Qt5::Widgets`. Add `Qt5::Core` to your link libraries. At least for me, the CMake files don't include transitive dependencies (so linking against `Qt5::Widgets` is not enough.)

Comment: Hi Anteru, I changed that line to `target_link_libraries(testproject Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core)` but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you check the linker paths manually? You should be linking against Qt5::Widgets, Qt5::Gui and Qt5::Core. Did anything change in the link errors after you added Qt5::Core?

Comment: Nothing changes after I added Qt-Core. However, instead of trying to create the build files in visual studi, i tried with mingw compiler with which i manage to build the project. So I believe I should check the linker path manually in visual studio

Comment: The transitive dependencies are included. `Qt5::Widgets` is enough.

Comment: Just a side note, Widgets depends on Core, so you don't need to explicitly link it. Unless you are linking against your library which depends on Widgets. Because QApplication is in Core modules, and only the parts that are used in your library will be linked from QtWidgets.